# How to turn off gcc compiler optimization to enable buffer overflow

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow, compiler-optimization

I'm working on a [homework problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333909/c-how-can-i-invoke-buffer-overflow-hw-problem-not-hacking) that requires disabling compiler optimization protection for it to work. I'm using gcc 4.4.1 on ubuntu linux, but can't figure out which flags are are the right ones. I realize it's architecture dependant - my machine runs w/ 32-bit Intel processor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

That's a good problem.  In order to solve that problem you will also have to disable ASLR otherwise the address of g() will be unpredictable.

Disable ASLR:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'
```

Disable canaries:

```
gcc overflow.c -o overflow -fno-stack-protector
```

After canaries and ASLR are disabled it should be a straight forward attack like the ones described in [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

Here is a list of security features used in ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features   You don't have to worry about NX bits, the address of g() will always be in a  executable region of memory because it is within the TEXT memory segment.  NX bits only come into play if you are trying to execute shellcode on the stack or heap, which is not required for this assignment as it is using [Return-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) (ROP or ROP Chain) which is commonly used to defeat the protection provided by the NX bit.

Now go and clobber that **EIP**!

Comment: thanks, I'll do just that :)

Oh - how do I re-enable the protection to un-crap my machine?.. My guess is 

sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

Comment: @sa125 yep, thats how its re-enabled. In fact thats how you switch on and off other kernel modules while the system is running ;)

Comment: Seems worth pointing out that on my system randomize_va_space defaulted to 2, not 1, so it's worth checking beforehand if you intend to re-enable it.

Comment: Actually the address of g() will very likely not be randomized by ASLR as it is part of the main binary. Only if you compile the binary with -PIE will it be randomized.

Comment: Modern Linux distros [configure GCC to build PIE executables by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux),   @RobertLarsen (and future readers).  You can use `gcc overflow.c -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie` to make tradition ELF executables, not shared objects.  (Then you don't have to disable ASLR for non-stack segments either system-wide or for this executable, which BTW is something GDB does.  No need to disable system-wide at all.)

Comment: Even in a non-PIE, the stack is still ASLRed, which is a problem for a code-injection attack (which would also need `-z execstack`).  But generally not a problem for a ROP attack like this which only depends on known absolute addresses in already-executable mappings, not the stack.  i.e. returning to some function that wouldn't normally be called, with interesting args in registers and/or on the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, modern systems here in 2021. When I wrote my answer six years ago PIE was not the default.
ROP does not need a full function. Small snippets of machine code can be chained together to achieve more or less anything. I realize you probably knew that.

Comment: @RobertLarsen: Yeah, I know your comment was correct at the time, mostly was addressing future readers.  And right, I said "function" because that was the goal in *this* question, and I had in mind using gadgets to piece together args for a function like `system()` or `execl()`, or something specific to the program, but yeah if you can find the bytes for a `syscall` instruction itself you could use that directly.

Answer (score 38):

Urm, **all** of the answers so far have been wrong with Rook's answer being correct.

Entering:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Followed by:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o bug bug.c
```

Disables ASLR, SSP/Propolice and Ubuntu's NoneXec (which was placed in 9.10, and fairly simple to work around see the [mprotect(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/mprotect.html) technique to map pages as executable and jmp) should help a little, however these "security features" are by no means infallible.  Without the `-z execstack' flag, pages have non-executable stack markings.

Comment: You did not read the guys link.   If you did you would know that  he is trying to execute g() which is a function that is compiled into the binary.  This is an address of a function.  NX bits come into play when you are trying to execute shellcode on the heap or stack,  his attack is far more simple.

Comment: I agree that everyone else is completely wrong,  its obvious that we are the only 2 that have exploited a buffer overflow.  However i still think my answer is more correct.

Comment: Hmm, just came across the link -- I thought it was just another generic, you're correct. I apologise.

Comment: I know this is a old post, but you can't use sudo with > < because it will not allow it. The command should be:
    **echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space**

Answer (score 29):

On newer distros (as of 2016), it seems that PIE is enabled by default so you will need to disable it explicitly when compiling.

Here's a little summary of commands which can be helpful when playing locally with buffer overflow exercises in general:

**Disable canary:**

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln_disable_canary -fno-stack-protector
```

**Disable DEP:**

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln_disable_dep -z execstack
```

**Disable PIE:**

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln_disable_pie -no-pie
```

**Disable all of protection mechanisms listed above (warning: for local testing only):**

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln_disable_all -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -no-pie
```

For 32-bit machines, you'll need to add the `-m32` parameter as well.

Comment: `-m32` is needed when you want to build 32-bit *code* on a *64-bit machine*.  Also, you can use `-fno-pie` to have the compiler generate asm that doesn't bother with PIE stuff, as well as `-no-pie` to have it not link that machine code into a PIE.  For 32-bit mode, `-fno-pie` will significantly simplify the asm, removing crap like `call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`.  For 64-bit mode, mostly just allowing `mov`-immediate instead of RIP-relative LEA for static addresses, and [more efficient indexing of static arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute).

Answer (score 9):

Try the `-fno-stack-protector` flag.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to disable ASLR in order to do a buffer overflow! Although ASLR is enabled (`kernel_randomize_va_space = 2`), it will not take effect unless the compiled executable is PIE. So unless you compiled your file with `-fPIC -pie` flag, ASLR will not take effect.

I think only disabling the canaries with `-fno-stack-protector` is enough.
If you want to check if ASLR is working or not (Position independent code must be set), use:

```
hardening-check executable_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't quote the entire page but the whole manual on optimisation is available here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

From the sounds of it you want at least `-O0`, the default, and:

> -fmudflap -fmudflapth -fmudflapir
>
> For front-ends that support it (C and C++), instrument all risky
>   pointer/array dereferencing
>   operations, some standard library
>   string/heap functions, and some other
>   associated constructs with
>   range/validity tests. Modules so
>   instrumented should be immune to
>   buffer overflows, invalid heap use,
>   and some other classes of C/C++
>   programming errors. The
>   instrumentation relies on a separate
>   runtime library (libmudflap), which
>   will be linked into a program if
>   -fmudflap is given at link time. Run-time behavior of the instrumented
>   program is controlled by the
>   MUDFLAP_OPTIONS environment variable.
>   See env MUDFLAP_OPTIONS=-help a.out
>   for its options.