# glibc: Disable "corrupted double-linked list" check with MALLOC_CHECK_=0

Tags: c, linux, libc

For experimental purposes, I want to disable *all* the heap corruptions checks of glibc. In particular, I want to disable this check in the `_int_free` function:

```
        /* Check that the top of the bin is not the record we are going to
           add (i.e., double free).  */
        if (__builtin_expect (old == p, 0))
          malloc_printerr ("double free or corruption (fasttop)");
```

and the following check in the `unlink_chunk` function:

```
unlink_chunk()
[...]
  if (__builtin_expect (fd->bk != p || bk->fd != p, 0))
    malloc_printerr ("corrupted double-linked list");
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750815/how-to-turn-off-glibc-run-time-protections/7509497#7509497) answer,  `MALLOC_CHECK_=0`  disables the runtimes checks. However, when I run `MALLOC_CHECK_=0 ./broken_program`, I still get the error message:

```
MALLOC_CHECK_=0 ./broken_program
double free or corruption (out)
```

What possibilities do I have to disable this unlink protection without recompiling the glibc?

Comment: The error logged does not correspond to the source code you listed.

Comment: Right, thanks -- I edited the question to reflect that I actually want to disable this error message (in fact, _any_ heap checking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750815/how-to-turn-off-glibc-run-time-protections/7509497#7509497) answer, MALLOC_CHECK_=0 disables the runtimes checks.

That answer is obsolete.  The environment variable it describes, which you are trying to use, is not documented for any recent version of Glibc.

> What possibilities do I have to disable this unlink protection without recompiling the glibc?

None, as far as I can tell, other than avoiding glibc's allocator altogether.  Note in particular these comments in the "Detecting heap corruption" section of [the online documentation of Glibc's allocator](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals):

> The common forms of corruption are handled with calls to
> `malloc_printerr`; these checks are always included in the code.
> Further checks use `assert` and are therefore disabled by building
> glibc with `-DNDEBUG`. In current glibc, both kinds of checks
> terminate the process via a call to `__libc_messsage`, which
> eventually calls `abort`. **Very old versions of glibc supported
> continuing in the present** [sic] **of heap corruption, but support for that has
> been removed.**

(Emphasis added.)

Note, then, that not only would you need to build your own glibc, you would need to *hack* glibc to remove the checks or to suppress action when they detect corruption.  There is no glibc configuration option available for that purpose.

Comment: That clarifies my question -- thank you!