# Strange pointer position in the stack

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, disassembly

I wrote this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ok(){}

int main()
{
  int k=1;
  int l=1337;
  int *p;
  p=NULL;
  p=&k;
  ok();
}
```

and I've disassembled it to see what the compiler does.
Using objdump I obtain:

```
0000000000400546 <main>:
  400546:       55                      push   rbp
  400547:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40054a:       48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
  40054e:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
  400555:       00 00 
  400557:       48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
  40055b:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  40055d:       c7 45 e8 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x1
  400564:       c7 45 ec 39 05 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x539
  40056b:       48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  400572:       00 
  400573:       48 8d 45 e8             lea    rax,[rbp-0x18]
  400577:       48 89 45 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
  40057b:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  400580:       48 8b 55 f8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400584:       64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
  40058b:       00 00 
  40058d:       74 05                   je     400594 <main+0x4e>
  40058f:       e8 8c fe ff ff          call   400420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  400594:       c9                      leave  
  400595:       c3                      ret    
  400596:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
  40059d:       00 00 00
```

I can understand everything except for the `mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0`, this correspond (I think)to `p=NULL;` but from `mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax` I know that my pointer is on `rbp-0x8` and it seems correct (the size of a pointer is 8bytes).

So why `mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0` is called on `rbp-0x10`?

Also I don't know why `xor    eax,eax` is called; for allignment?(if so why don't use `nop`).
P.S I know that is sets eax to zero, but why ?

Comment: Your pointer "p" is actually at `[rbp-0x10]` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414763/what-does-the-mov-rax-qword-ptr-fs0x28-assembly-instruction-do for more information on what `[rbp-0x8]` is being used for (specifically, the `mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28` immediately preceding it).

Comment: To not assume, you can have intermixed assembly with source code in objdump output. Compile with debug info: `gcc -g file.c` and run `objdump -S a.out` or `objdump --source a.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these lines

```
  6   int k=1;
  7   int l=1337;
  8   int *p;
  9   p=NULL;
 10   p=&k;
```

It is clear that these assembler instructions correspond to

```
  6   int k=1;
  40055d:       c7 45 e8 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x1

  7   int l=1337;
  400564:       c7 45 ec 39 05 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x539

  9   p=NULL;
  40056b:       48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  400572:       00 

 10   p=&k;
  400573:       48 8d 45 e8             lea    rax,[rbp-0x18]
  400577:       48 89 45 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
```

So the local variable `p`  is placed at `[rbp-0x10]` and occupies a `QWORD` starting at `[rbp-0x10]` through `[rbp-0x8]` ( `rbp-0x10 + 0x8 == rbp-0x8`)

Comment: but the space between p (on rbp-0x10) and l (on rbp-0x14) is 0x04. Isn't a pointer 8 bytes long? How he can fit in a space of 0x04?

Comment: @Ofey  The space at addresses rbp -0x14 and rbp - 0x10 is occupied by the variable l. The space at addresses rbp-0x10 and rbp-0x8 is occupied by the pointer p. rbp-0x10 + 8 == rbp-0x8.

Comment: That's what i was mising! Thank you!