# Why is there extra space between stack control data and local variables?

Tags: c, x86, stack, buffer-overflow

I am working through the [OverTheWire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/) Narnia wargame and I don't completely understand one of my buffer overflow solutions.

The following code is what is confusing me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char buf[128];

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Usage: %s argument\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    printf("%s", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

My solution uses the lack on length checking on the `strcpy` function to overflow `main`'s return address. There are 8 bytes of unused memory between the end of the 128 bytes reserved for `buf` and the start of the stack frame control data (the saved `ebp` and return address). Hence, my payload needs to be 8 bytes longer than I originally thought to overflow the control data (144 bytes instead of 136). Stack canaries are not being used. What are the possible reasons for the 8 bytes of unused memory?

uname -a: Linux melinda 4.9.15-x86_64-linode81 #1 SMP Fri Mar 17 09:47:36 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Here is the output of `disassemble main` in `gdb`:

```
   0x0804845d <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x0804845e <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048460 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048463 <+6>:     sub    $0x90,%esp
   0x08048469 <+12>:    cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804846d <+16>:    jne    0x8048490 <main+51>
   0x0804846f <+18>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048472 <+21>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048474 <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048478 <+27>:    movl   $0x8048560,(%esp)
   0x0804847f <+34>:    call   0x8048310 <printf@plt>
   0x08048484 <+39>:    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
   0x0804848b <+46>:    call   0x8048340 <exit@plt>
   0x08048490 <+51>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048493 <+54>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048496 <+57>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048498 <+59>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804849c <+63>:    lea    0x10(%esp),%eax
   0x080484a0 <+67>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080484a3 <+70>:    call   0x8048320 <strcpy@plt>
   0x080484a8 <+75>:    lea    0x10(%esp),%eax
   0x080484ac <+79>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x080484b0 <+83>:    movl   $0x8048574,(%esp)
   0x080484b7 <+90>:    call   0x8048310 <printf@plt>
   0x080484bc <+95>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x080484c1 <+100>:   leave
   0x080484c2 <+101>:   ret
```

So I guess it's the `and    $0xfffffff0,%esp` command that's causing the extra space, but why is that instruction necessary?

Comment: What does `uname -a` show. What does `/etc/issue.net` have in it and what version off gcc is shown by `gcc --version`. Sounds like it might be alignment related, but depending on how old the Linux is it may just be the ay your old compiler laid out the locals.

Comment: I don't have access to a computer that I can install putty on or an internet connected Linux machine, I will look tonight

Comment: uname -a: Linux melinda 4.9.15-x86_64-linode81 #1 SMP Fri Mar 17 09:47:36 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Comment: cat /etc/issue.net: This is the OverTheWire game server. More information on http://www.overthewire.org/wargames

Please note that wargame usernames are no longer level<X>, but wargamename<X>
e.g. vortex4, semtex2, ...

Note: at this moment, blacksun is not available.

Comment: Can you add `-S` to the _GCC_ command line and add to your question the output of the generated `.s` file?

Comment: Stack canaries [are being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325713/why-does-this-memory-address-have-a-random-value).

Comment: I agree they are being used in the output of `gcc -S narnia2.c` but the actual program you need to hack has been compiled with extra flags to remove the stack protection, I'm not sure exactly the command used as I didn't compile it, the compiled binary and source are provided for you on the box

Comment: I'll change my question to make that more clear, as it isn't at the moment

Comment: I have included the output of the main function from gdb so you can see the exact instructions being executed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1062143/371250 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175281/what-does-it-mean-to-align-the-stack

Comment: You can [override this behavior in _GCC_](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) by using `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` but be forewarned that calling into some _C_ library functions or external libraries (or anyone that calls them directly or indirectly) may fault because of alignment issues.

Comment: `and $0xfffffff0,%esp` makes sure that the stack is 16-byte aligned per the i386 Linux System V ABI. That instruction effectively rounds _ESP_ down to the nearest 16-byte boundary.You'll see this instruction in the generation of `main` by GCC on i386 targets. The idea is that when you call another function, at the time of the call the stack needs to be on such a boundary

Comment: Beautiful, thanks guys, all the stuff above has everything I wanted to know