# How to get invariant thread-stack address for GCC compiled executable?

Tags: c++, aslr

My question is based on this tiny `stkaddr.cpp` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("&argc = %p\n", &argc);
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2019, I know that I can use linker option `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` to have invariant(constant) local variable address across each run. May be we call it "no ASLR".

[image: VC2019 no ASLR compile and run]

With `/DYNAMICBASE:NO`, each run of the exe we see the **same address** for `&argc`.

Then I'd like to ask how can I achieve this for a gcc compiled Linux program.

On Ubuntu Linux 20.04, with gcc 9.4.0, I tried `-no-pie`, but no effect.

[image: GCC variant local var address.]

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340455/5754656

Comment: Thank you. Yes, root user executing `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` makes `&argc` constant, even not compiling with `-no-pie`. Then I'm wondering must we do that system-wide? I hope it should be at least user-wide, or better, session-wide.

Comment: @JimmChen The assumption you're making - that it is possible/dependable on - is IMHO misguided. Even with /DYNAMICBASE:NO, you can get different address after a reboot, updates, change in moon phase, etc. None of this is guaranteed. When a process starts up, be it on Windows or on Linux, there is very little in the way of assumptions that one can make about the available address space. `&stkadr` is what you should use for the stack address. Don't assume it's constant across executions, whether ASLR is enabled or not.

Comment: Why would you even care what the exact address of the stack *is* to start with?? I smell an XY problem.

Comment: For pedagogical purpose. I need to run two similar programs several times to record their behavior. I will record screen shots during my experiments. So, my screenshot should reflect the "real" difference of the two programs. So the "non-real" difference of stack pointer variation looks quite distracting.